# Jquery Removing '0' in textbox after any value is entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, onkeyup

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1fvoqz8/1/)

Initially the textbox won't have any  value.

If any value is entered and it was emptied '0' will be added in it.

But the '0' is not removed after entering any value to it.

How can i remove the '0' if any value is entered it.

Here is my Code :

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val() == ""){
   $('.qty').val('0');
    }else if($(this).val() > 0){
   $(this).val().replace(0,'');
   }
});
```

Comment: better to use `placeholder`.

Comment: I don't need the placeholder.while the value is empty i want to remove the '0' after the value is entered.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r1fvoqz8/12/

Comment: Sorry mistakenly given wrong answer'

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val() == ""){
   $('.qty').val('0');
   }else if($(this).val() > 0){
   console.log($(this).val());
   $(this).val().replace(0,'');
   }
    if($(this).val()!=0){
        var text = $(this).val();
        alert(text.slice(0,1));
        if(text.slice(0,1)==0)
        {
            $(this).val(text.slice(1,text.length));   
        }
      }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/atate143/r1fvoqz8/11/)

Comment: @Amy Sorry for trolling your answer too, but isn't it really simpler solution: http://jsfiddle.net/0kgebyor/ ??? BTW, now lazy OP get his jsFiddle...

Comment: @A.Wolff better luck for next time :)

Comment: @Amy ya ;) But your answer still accepts non numeric value where class name `qty` would suggest only numeric ones, just saying

Comment: @A.Wolff he didnt mention anything about input format

Comment: @Amy You are correct even it seems obvious he is looking for integer value otherwise why using class name qty (quantity) and why checking for `$(this).val() > 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 
$('.qty').val('0');

Add palceholder.

```js
$('.qty').attr('placeholder','0');
```

Comment: Read comments before answering

Comment: Take care next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If `placeholder` isn't an option, you could parse value to integer:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var val = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    this.value = val ? val: 0;
});
```

Comment: Please provide me in fiddle link

Comment: @faizphp ***WAIT***, you have to show minimal effort, good bye!

Comment: @Amy How is this fiddle relevant to this answer?

Comment: He wants to remove zero if he typing anything than zero

Answer (score 0):

`.replace()` returns the modified string, you need to store it back into the value. Try this:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $('.qty').val('0');
    } else if ($(this).val() > 0) {
        console.log($(this).val());
        $(this).val(function() {
            return this.value.replace(/^0+/, '');
        });
    }
});
```

I've also changed the `replace()` call to use a regular expression, so it only removes zeroes at the beginning of the input. Otherwise, it will change `102` to `12`.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/r1fvoqz8/8/)

Comment: He didnt mentioned he only wants for number only in question

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using `blur` and `focus` instead of `keyup` :

```
$('.qty').blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') this.value = '0';
}).focus(function() {
    if (this.value == '0') this.value = '';
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SylvainThrd/r1fvoqz8/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="0">


$(document).ready(function(){
    var Input = $('input[name=test]');
    var value= Input.val();

    $(Input).focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == value)
        {
             $(this).val("");
        }
    }).keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length == 0)
        {
            $(this).val(value);
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val() == ""){
   $('.qty').val('');
   }else if($(this).val() > 0){
   console.log($(this).val());
   $(this).val().replace(0,'');
   }
});
```

Comment: just you to remove zero in $('.qty').val('0');

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace 0, replace with whole value using javascript Number function

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(){
   if($(this).val() == ""){
   $('.qty').val('0');
   }else if($(this).val() > 0){
   console.log($(this).val());
   $(this).val(Number($(this).val()))
   }
});
```

[refer jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1fvoqz8/12/)